# ipython time data does not match format using apply and lambda

Tags: python, datetime, lambda, ipython, apply

I put this in, which I thought should work:

```
dayv['TDAYDATE'] = dayv['TDAYDATE'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(str(x),'%Y%m'))
```

The Error it returns:

```
ValueError: time data '2009-04-01 00:00:00' does not match format '%Y%m'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your datetime format does not match the actual string in the column , you can given format `%Y%m` which matches strings like - `201509` , etc, and not `2009-04-01 00:00:00` . Assuming you are using a `pandas` `Series` or `DataFrame` , you can simply use [`pandas.to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) -

```
dayv['TDAYDATE'] = pd.to_datetime(dayv['TDAYDATE'])
```

If you want to make it faster, you can also supply the format as -

```
dayv['TDAYDATE'] = pd.to_datetime(dayv['TDAYDATE'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Demo -

```
In [75]: dayv = pd.DataFrame([['2009-04-01 00:00:00'],['2009-04-01 00:00:00'],['2009-04-01 00:00:00']],columns=['TDAYDATE'])

In [76]: dayv
Out[76]:
              TDAYDATE
0  2009-04-01 00:00:00
1  2009-04-01 00:00:00
2  2009-04-01 00:00:00

In [77]: dayv['TDAYDATE'] = pd.to_datetime(dayv['TDAYDATE'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

In [78]: dayv
Out[78]:
    TDAYDATE
0 2009-04-01
1 2009-04-01
2 2009-04-01
```

---

If you are not using pandas, then change the format string to `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` . Example -

```
dayv['TDAYDATE'] = dayv['TDAYDATE'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(str(x),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```